# Running "hostname -i" no longer shows all my addresses

Tags: networking, server, ssh, hostname

I changed my hostname on Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Now running `hostname -i` gets rid most of my addresses except for one.

Instead it's output is:

```
127.0.1.1
```

It used to be: `ipv6_address%eth0 ipv6_address%eth1 ipv6_address%2 ipv4_address ipv4_address ipv4_address ipv4_address`.

/etc/hostname: `ubuntu-rany-01`

/etc/hosts:

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
127.0.1.1 rany-01 rany-01
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Is there anyway to get my addresses back?

Comment: What is the content of yours /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts ?

Comment: This is because in `/etc/hosts` you find the entry 127.0.1.1  YourLinuxBoxName.  This particular localhost entry (every address in `127/8` is localhost) is used by DNSmasq.  It is safe to ignore.

Comment: @SpasSpasov I updated the question

Comment: @jawtheshark could you add this as an answer :)

Comment: I'll do so, but Spas Spasov answer is actually right too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in `/etc/hosts` you find the entry `127.0.1.1 YourLinuxBoxName`.

This particular localhost entry (every address in `127/8` is `localhost`) is used by DNSmasq. It is safe to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You should change next line:

```
127.0.1.1 rany-01 rany-01
```

in `/etc/hosts`.  It must be:

```
127.0.1.1 ubuntu-rany-01
```

Or you can change the content of `/etc/hostname`: `rany-01` instead of `ubuntu-rany-01`.

Comment: DigitalOcean doesn't want me to change this file according to documentation.

Comment: That's just because if you change it and make a mess, your system would become non-functional and then they get support calls.  If you limit yourself to the edit Spas suggests, it will be fine.